# How to get the index or the id of the image hovered -Jquery/Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I know this question might sound repetitive, as many people must have asked this. I search through most of the stack overflow answers and didn't quite find a fit to my issue here.
I want to get the id or the index of the hovered image. below is the attachement:

[image]

the icon as seen, when hovered should display the info presented in the content. I need to first get the index of the icon hovered and display the content accordingly.. i tried this:

```
 $('li span.account-info-icon').on("mouseover", function(event){
                    var myindex =  $(this).index();
                    console.log(myindex);
    });
```

for both icons on hover gives me the same index..
HTML:

```
<ul>
<li class="hover">
<label class="bar">-----000-------1012-TEST</label>
<span class="account-info-icon"></span>
</li>
<li>
<label class="bar">---000----test--tian---1007-TEST</label>
<span class="account-info-icon"></span>
</li>

</ul>
```

any ideas on how this could be done??
Thanks!

Comment: Not easy to debug unless you show your html code

Comment: nothing shown has an ID. If you want index,  what specifically do you want the index of?

Comment: well, index of the li hovered, so that i can display the content of that <li>.ex: if i hover over the first <li>, it should give an index and depending on that index, i can grab the respective <li> content..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your `span`s are going to be index 1 -- they are the second child of their parent element (the `li`s).  If you want to get the index of the `li`s, use `$(this).parent().index();` e.g.

```
$('li span.account-info-icon').on("mouseover", function(event){
    var myindex =  $(this).parent().index();
    console.log(myindex);
});
```